# http post subscription and try catch

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, angular

I use Angular2's `http.post` and sometimes the headers are not send to the CORS server. So I want to try till the request succeeds. But this code hangs in an endless loop?

```
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

 this.again = true;
        while (this.again==true) {
           http.post('https://localhost:44300/account/getip', "", { headers: headers })
                .subscribe(
                (res2) => {
                    try {
                        this.ip = res2.json();
                        this.ipstr = this.ip.replace(/\./g, '-');
                        this.again = false;
                     }
                    catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                }
                );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch errors from request you could either:

- Use the second callback of the `subscribe` method:

  ```
  http.post('https://localhost:44300/account/getip', "", { headers: headers })
          .subscribe(
            (res2) => {
              (...)
            },
            (error) => {
              (...)
            }
          );
  }
  ```
- Use the `catch` operator:

  ```
  http.post('https://localhost:44300/account/getip', "", { headers: headers })
          .catch((error) => {
            (...)
          })
          .subscribe(
            (res2) => {
              (...)
            }
          );
  }
  ```

Regarding retrying requests, you could leverage the `retry` operator this way (with a `timeout` one):

```
this.http.get('https://localhost:44300/account/getip',
          { search: params })
    .retryWhen(error => error.delay(500))
    .timeout(2000, return new Error('delay exceeded'))
    .map(res => res.json().postalCodes);
```

You can see the use of `delay` to wait for an amount of time before executing a new request...

This article could interest you as well:

- https://jaxenter.com/reactive-programming-http-and-angular-2-124560.html

Comment: I have problems to use the functions. I tried: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
`, but then the app freezes

Comment: Really :-( Did you try: `import 'rxjs/Rx';`. Just to see what happens...

Comment: this also freezes my browser

Comment: Could you open the JavaScript console to see a bit more about what is loaded by SystemJS?

Comment: I am stupid. I still had the `while` loop in my code. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I still get error.delay is not a function. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `retry` operator:

```
http.post('https://localhost:44300/account/getip', "", { headers: headers })
.retry(3)              
.subscribe((res2) => {
  this.ip = res2.json();
  this.ipstr = this.ip.replace(/\./g, '-');
})
```

Comment: TypeError: http.post(...).retry is not a function

Comment: As all operators, you need to import it `import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';`

Comment: this crashes my application

Comment: Then try Thierrys answer.

Comment: maybe the import is wrong? I have to cast to `<any>`

Comment: Where do you have to cast?

Comment: `http.post` . otherwise `retry(3)` does not exist also with import

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Try Thierrys answer.

Comment: same problems there

Comment: I am stupid. I still had the while loop in my code. Now it works. Thanks!